# R Shiny checkboxGroupInput - Actions based on different combinations?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with R shiny to build a simple plotting app, and I don't think I really understand how `checkboxGroupInput` works, and the documentation from the R shiny app website isn't too helpful, so I was hoping to get some clarification.

This is what my `checkboxGroupInput` looks like:

```
checkboxGroupInput("trend1DisplayOptions", "Graph Display Options",
                                    choiceNames = list("Connect Data Points", "Display Loess Smoother with Uncertainty Bounds"),
                                    choiceValues = list("connect", "loess"),
                                    selected = "connect")
```

So, I'm essentially looking to display 4 different "types" of plots depending on which checkboxes are selected (whether to display loess/connect points or not).

And in my `server` code, here are the `if/else` statements:

```
if (input$trend1DisplayOptions == "connect" && input$trend1DisplayOptions != "loess") {
  # Only connect points
  p <- plot_ly(x = df2$labels, y = df2$values, type = 'scatter', mode='lines+markers') %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(type = "category")) 
  p

# Probably wrong way to check
} else if (input$trend1DisplayOptions == "connect" && input$trend1DisplayOptions == "loess") {
  # Should display nothing

# Probably wrong way to check
} else if (input$trend1DisplayOptions != "connect" && input$trend1DisplayOptions == "loess") {
  # Should display nothing

} else if (is.null(input$trend1DisplayOptions)) {
  # Should show
  p <- plot_ly(x = x_labels, y = df$values, type = 'scatter') %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"), title = input$trendTitle) 
  p

}
```

The issue I'm running into is that when both checkboxes are selected, the `shiny` app should display nothing, but it still displays the plot from the first `if` statement (i.e. when only "connect" is selected). And, when neither are selected, I get a `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` error.

What did I misunderstand about `checkboxGroupInput`?

I can see the issue is assuming the input values are equal to 2 things at the same time. So, what is the correct way to check if checkbox 1 is selected and checkbox 2 isn't, and vice versa? Also, I've searched on this forum to see how to deal with when neither are selected, and it seems `is.null()` is the right way to go. Why isn't it working for my case?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I misread one of the S.O. answers. I should be using `%in%` and `!(... %in% ...)` to check for combinations.

Here is the correct version if anyone needs it:

```
if ("connect" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions && !("loess" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions)) {
  p <- plot_ly(x = df2$labels, y = df2$values, type = 'scatter', mode='lines+markers') %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(type = "category")) 
  p


} else if (!("connect" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions) && "loess" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions) {
  # Should display nothing


} else if ("connect" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions && "loess" %in% input$trend1DisplayOptions) {
  # Should display nothing


} else if (is.null(input$trend1DisplayOptions)) {
  p <- plot_ly(x = df2$labels, y = df2$values, type = 'scatter') %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"), title = input$trendTitle) 
  p

}
```